# Is there a way to be alerted when a view controller or any object for that matter is released because of a retain count of 0 in ARC?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

There used to be dealloc but since ARC that's gone.

I need some way to be alerted of exactly when an object is freed (and I'd rather not use Instruments since it's really slow and just not working for me right now.)

Answer (score 5):

That's not correct, the method `dealloc` of `NSObject` still exists.
[See Docs here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/dealloc)

Comment: Oh, wow - I could have sworn I'd gotten compilation errors for trying to use dealloc before. Thanks!

Comment: ARC forbids you to call `[super dealloc]`, maybe that's why you got compilation errors.